# How to draw a point beside a line?

Tags: vector, drawing, 2d, line, point

I have an arrow that can point at any direction. I need to draw a point alongside, at a specific distance. The point needs to remain on the correct side of the arrow. How do I do this? I know the angle of the arrow.

Illustration:

--->

o

Comment: Could you please go into more detail of what you want, my current understanding is the dot will always be 90º to the arrow? Or did you want the dot always below the arrow?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector representing the arrow, you could make a unit vector then times it by the length that you want and place the point at the end of the new shortened vector.

Answer (score 0):

You already know the angle and location of the arrow, so what you should do is just draw the point based on the arrows end-point (the blunt end-point) and in the direction of the arrow + 90º.